# Updating a SQL Server database table with a dropdown list inside a gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, visual-studio-2012

I have a web form with a few text boxes and a grid view. The grid view displays specific data from a SQLdatasource once an id number is entered. The information in the grid view, in theory, can be deleted or edited via a drop down list. The issue is that when a selection is made in the drop down list and the update button is clicked, the grid view refreshes to the original selection.

I've researched what I could possibly be doing wrong, but I think I've looked at it so long I'm just spinning my wheels. I have a feeling it might be some formatting error from moving around the C# code through trial and error, or it could be something that I just don't have in there. I figure another set of eyes couldn't hurt.

Thanks

Here is my HTML:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 50%;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="main outside">
            <div class="user">
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Name:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Test User ID:"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="baby">

                <asp:GridView ID="grdvwBabyInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="id_baby" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_baby" HeaderText="id_baby" InsertVisible="False" 
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_baby" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_user" HeaderText="id_user" 
                            SortExpression="id_user" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Relation" SortExpression="relation_to_baby">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpDwnRelation" runat="server" 

                                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("relation_to_baby") %>' AutoPostBack="False">
                                    <asp:ListItem>mother</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>father</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>brother</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>sister</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>aunt</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>uncle</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>grandmother</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>grandfather</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>niece</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>nephew</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>friend</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("relation_to_baby") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Baby's Gender" SortExpression="sex_of_baby">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpDwnGender" runat="server" 
                                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("sex_of_baby") %>' AutoPostBack="False">
                                    <asp:ListItem>a baby boy</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>a baby girl</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>twins</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>triplets</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>unknown</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sex_of_baby") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est. Due Date" SortExpression="due_date">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("due_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="baby_first_name" HeaderText="Baby's First Name" 
                            SortExpression="baby_first_name" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bbvs_d01ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [bbuser_baby] WHERE [id_baby] = @original_id_baby AND [id_user] = @original_id_user AND [relation_to_baby] = @original_relation_to_baby AND [sex_of_baby] = @original_sex_of_baby AND (([due_date] = @original_due_date) OR ([due_date] IS NULL AND @original_due_date IS NULL)) AND (([baby_first_name] = @original_baby_first_name) OR ([baby_first_name] IS NULL AND @original_baby_first_name IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [bbuser_baby] ([id_user], [relation_to_baby], [sex_of_baby], [due_date], [baby_first_name]) VALUES (@id_user, @relation_to_baby, @sex_of_baby, @due_date, @baby_first_name)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [bbuser_baby] WHERE ([id_user] = @id_user)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bbuser_baby] SET [id_user] = @id_user, [relation_to_baby] = @relation_to_baby, [sex_of_baby] = @sex_of_baby, [due_date] = @due_date, [baby_first_name] = @baby_first_name WHERE [id_baby] = @original_id_baby AND [id_user] = @original_id_user AND [relation_to_baby] = @original_relation_to_baby AND [sex_of_baby] = @original_sex_of_baby AND (([due_date] = @original_due_date) OR ([due_date] IS NULL AND @original_due_date IS NULL)) AND (([baby_first_name] = @original_baby_first_name) OR ([baby_first_name] IS NULL AND @original_baby_first_name IS NULL))">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_id_baby" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_id_user" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_relation_to_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_sex_of_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_due_date" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_baby_first_name" Type="String" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="id_user" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="relation_to_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="sex_of_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="due_date" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="baby_first_name" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTest" Name="id_user" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="id_user" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="relation_to_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="sex_of_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="due_date" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="baby_first_name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_id_baby" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_id_user" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_relation_to_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_sex_of_baby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_due_date" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_baby_first_name" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

            </div>
            <div class="testbox">
                </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="buttons"><asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSave_Click" /><asp:Button ID="btnLoad" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="btnLoad_Click" /></div></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace BabyEditForm
{
    public partial class EditForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
        }

        protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string source = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["bbvs_d01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;            

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);            
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader readerBBUser = null;

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from bbuser WHERE id_user='" + txtTest.Text + "'", conn);


            readerBBUser = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (readerBBUser.Read())
            {
            txtName.Text = (readerBBUser["name"].ToString());
            txtEmail.Text = (readerBBUser["email"].ToString());
            txtUserName.Text = (readerBBUser["username"].ToString());            
            }          
            conn.Close();
        }       

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string source = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["bbvs_d01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdA = new SqlCommand("UPDATE bbuser SET name = @name, email = @email, username = @username WHERE id_user='" + txtTest.Text + "'", conn);

            cmdA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            cmdA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmdA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);

            cmdA.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand cmdB = new SqlCommand("UPDATE bbuser_baby SET relation_to_baby = @relation_to_baby, sex_of_baby = @sex_of_baby, due_date = @due_date, baby_first_name = @baby_first_name WHERE id_user'" + txtTest.Text + "'", conn);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in grdvwBabyInfo.Rows)
                {
                    string dropDownRelationText = ((DropDownList)
                    row.FindControl("drpDwnRelation")).SelectedItem.Value;
                    Response.Write(dropDownRelationText);

                    string dropDownGenderText = ((DropDownList)
                    row.FindControl("drpDwnGender")).SelectedItem.Value;
                    Response.Write(dropDownGenderText);

                    cmdB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relation_to_baby", dropDownRelationText);
                    cmdB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex_of_baby", dropDownGenderText);
                    grdvwBabyInfo.DataBind();
                    cmdB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }                    
            conn.Close();

                }
            }           
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove "if (!IsPostBack)" from your button_save click?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to interchange the following FROM:

```
grdvwBabyInfo.DataBind(); 
cmdB.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

TO:

```
cmdB.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
grdvwBabyInfo.DataBind();
```